# TrueCaller SDK into iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sdk

I have to intrgate truecalled SDK into my app,
which will authenticate user and I will get response from truecaller which I have to use throughout the app.

I have downloaded the SDK from

```
https://developer.truecaller.com/
```

and integrated into my code.
I am able to login using truecaller and It ask for permission.
If I click OK, 
it opens the browser and shows some JSON,

like this

```
{"code":404, "message":"HTTP 404 not found"}
```

I have used same URL provided by SDK,

```
https://si568c53146f0a4130bf723b62d52361b6.truecallerdevs.com
```

Following are the screen shots shows the flow

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow this steps:

Add the entry truesdk under LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in into your Info.plist file

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
<string>truesdk</string>
</array>
```

[image]

Add the associated domain provided by Truecaller (for example applinks:si44524554ef8e45b5aa83ced4e96d5xxx.truecallerdevs.com) in Your project -> Capabilities > Associated Domains. The prefix 'applinks:' is needed for universal links to function properly.

**Important:** Replace the 'https://' part from the provided app link with "applinks:". ie https://si44524554ef8e45b5aa83ced4e96d5xxx.truecallerdevs.com should become applinks:si44524554ef8e45b5aa83ced4e96d5xxx.truecallerdevs.com while adding to entitlements.

(Note that there is no http:// or https:// prefix when setting up the applinks:)

Comment: I already followed those steps, they provide this all in their documentation too.. still of no use

Comment: Where to find APP link?